# RegEx to extract numeric value immediately before a search character /string found

Tags: regex

what would be the best regEx to extract all the number (only numbers) before a search string ?

```
ABC Y C S       1 $  46CC MAN 25/ 31
```

Need to extract 25 in this case, but its not fixed length ? Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 '\d+(?=/)'
```

should work. see test with grep:

```
kent$  echo "ABC Y C S       1 $  46CC MAN 25/ 31 "|grep -Po '\d+(?=/)'
25
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl regex:

```
while ($subject =~ m!\d+(?=.*/)!g) {
    # matched text = $&
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
46
25
```

So basically keep matching, as long as a `/` exist somewhere later.